# JS Datatables - filtering table from combo box in header

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I have the following datatable which uses the js datatable plugin from https://datatables.net/

[image: TracerDataTable]

The datatable is set using the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tracerTable').DataTable({
        "bInfo": false,
        "order": [[2, "desc"]], //order by date created
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { aTargets: [3], "bSortable": false },
            { aTargets: [4], "bSortable": false },
            { aTargets: [5], "bSortable": false }
        ]
    });
}
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to update the JS to allow me to filter on the 'Type' column using a dropdown with tickbox options within in the table header (just like the filter option in excel - see image below). I would want this for selecting Water and Oil Tracers, but not showing Gas tracers.

[image: ExcelExample]

If this is not possible within the datatable plugin, can anyone suggest a plugin which would provide this functionality?

Comment: Actually, that is possible.  Take a look at this: https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/regex.html

Comment: This would be easy if the filtering is done on the table footer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of the [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) plugin, append it to the header of your DataTables by targeting the desired column (in your case `1`), get the checked values, join it with `|` (the or operand) then use [`search`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) API.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  initComplete: function() {
    this.api().columns([1]).every(function() {
      var column = this;
      var select = $('<select class="selectpicker" data-show-content="false" data-none-selected-text="Position" multiple><option value="" >Show All</option></select>')
        .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())//use $(column.footer() to append it to the table footer instead
        .on('changed.bs.select', function(e) {
          var val = $(this).val();
          var fVal = val.join("|")
          column
            .search(fVal, true, false)
            .draw();
        }); //select

      column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
      }); //column.data
    }); //this.api
  } //initComplete
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/kunt518t/4/) for more details, I suggest *moving the filter function on the footer* as clicking the dropdown button on the table header will sort the table.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The fiddle was very useful.

Comment: Do you know how to refresh the values in the dropdown if the table source has changed? @Sachi Tekina

Comment: You can reload the table then, i think it will also refresh the dropdown values